# Install xunbug on mac

Tags: xcode, cordova

Anyone know how to install Xun bug on mac.?

I have followd guid lines that they provied.But when i build , xcode sent folowing error..

"**line 3: /phone/version/mac/bin/profile.sh: No such file or directory** "

Plese help me?

Comment: I have a sampe problem.?